# Convert XSD from Salami Slice to Venetian Blinds design

Tags: xml

I'm looking for a tool that can parse an XSD file and convert from one layout to another.

I have two XSD files that I would like to merge, but they have a lot of elements with same names but different meaning, data type, or properties. So using a tool to automate the merging results in an invalid XSD, because the tool is unable to resolve the duplicates. (I'm currently using Liquid XML Studio).

Sample file 1:

```
  <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="Author" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="CatalogueID" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="Book">
    <xsd:complexType> 
      <xsd:sequence> 
        <xsd:element ref="Title"/> 
        <xsd:element ref="Author"/>
        <xsd:element ref="CatalogueID"/>
      </xsd:sequence> 
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

Sample file 2:

```
  <xsd:element name="Publisher" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xsd:element name="CatalogueID" type="xsd:integer"/>
  <xsd:element name="WebArticle">
    <xsd:complexType> 
      <xsd:sequence> 
        <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Publisher"/>
        <xsd:element ref="CatalogueID"/>
      </xsd:sequence> 
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

I believe this happens because the XSD files follow the Salami Slice design, so their individual elements are declared at the top level.

So one workaround I could think of is first re-format the files from Salami Slice to Russian Doll, to limit the scope of the similarly-named elements.

Is there a tool that could help me do this in a fully or semi automated manner?

(I will gladly accept answers even weeks, months or years from now. Thank you.)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and I am now looking for a third party to transform Russian Doll to Salami Slice format.